# Express JS session store implementation: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I am trying to add my own session storage implementation in Node Express:

```
var cma = parseInt(process.env["COOKIE_MAX_AGE"]);
console.log("CMA: " + cma);

self.app.use(express.bodyParser());
self.app.use(express.cookieParser());

var sessionStore = new SessionStore();

self.app.use(express.session({
    secret: '123456...',
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: cma,
        secure: true
        }
}));
```

But I get the following error message:

```
store.on('disconnect', function(){ storeReady = false; });
      ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

My `SessionStore` implements the required methods in [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

Does it mean I am supposed to implement a `on` method in my `SessionStore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the [base session store class](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/43917dd074158f7f996f36281bf863ae7380ec46/session/store.js#L29) inherits from `events.EventEmitter`. You need to make sure either the base SessionStore or EventEmitter are in your class's prototype chain, then you'll have `.on` and the other event binding methods. AFAIK there's no requirement that you ever emit any specific events, however.